# Error creating Stored Procedure in Visual Studio 2015 Dataproject

Tags: visual-studio

When I create a Stored Procedure in a Visual Studio DataProject like this:

```
CREATE Procedure myProcedure
   (@Para1 AS INT,
   @Para2 AS NVARCHAR(10)
AS
  ...
```

I get the error "SQL72007 Error at syntax check: incorrect syntax near CREATE." (translated from German)

I've already set the target platform to 'SQL Server 2014'

The script is of type "Not in build".

If I copy and paste the complete Stored Procedure into SQL Server Management Studio, all works fine.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand it, but if I place "GO" before the "CREATE"-Statement, it works:

```
GO
CREATE Procedure myProcedure
...
```